# MySql ifnull and count bug?

Tags: mysql, ifnull

MySql version: 5.7.18-15-log,

My classmate asked a question:

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(1) Counts, 
  IFNULL((SELECT SUM(c.RealMoney) FROM PayRecord c WHERE a.id=c.orderid), 0) money
FROM `Order` a
WHERE a.UserId ='not exists user id';
```

he got a result :

> Counts:0  money 8000

,
and he asked why??? no record, why have money???

I tryed and found it's like a bug, For example:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(1) Counts, 
  IFNULL((SELECT c.RealMoney FROM PayRecord c WHERE a.id=c.orderid), 0) money
FROM `Order` a
WHERE  a.id='bc7ba7ed-44f2-4686-b5ae-df65e8cc566f';
```

return

> Counts:1  money:8622

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(1) Counts, 
  IFNULL((SELECT SUM(c.RealMoney) FROM PayRecord c WHERE a.id=c.orderid), 0) money
FROM `Order` a
WHERE a.UserId ='not exists user id';
```

return

> Counts:0  money:8622

It seems the first sql will cached,
and second sql will use this cache...

DDL like :

```
CREATE TABLE `Order` (
  `Id` char(36) NOT NULL ,
  `UserId` char(36) NOT NULL ,
  ......,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`,`CreateTime`),
  KEY `idx_RestId` (`RestId`),
  KEY `idx_CreateTime` (`CreateTime`),
  KEY `idx_UserId` (`UserId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 
/*!50500 PARTITION BY RANGE  COLUMNS(CreateTime)
(
 PARTITION p201712 VALUES LESS THAN ('2018-01-01') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p201801 VALUES LESS THAN ('2018-02-01') ENGINE = InnoDB) */


CREATE TABLE `PayRecord` (
  `Id` char(36) NOT NULL ,
  `OrderId` char(36) NOT NULL ,
  `RealMoney` int(11) NOT NULL ,
  .......
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`,`CreateTime`),
  KEY `idx_OrderId` (`OrderId`),
  KEY `idx_PayId` (`PayId`),
  KEY `idx_CreateTime` (`CreateTime`),
  KEY `idx_BrandId_RestId` (`BrandId`,`RestId`),
  KEY `idx_RestId` (`RestId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
/*!50500 PARTITION BY RANGE  COLUMNS(CreateTime)
(
 PARTITION p201712 VALUES LESS THAN ('2018-01-01') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p201801 VALUES LESS THAN ('2018-02-01') ENGINE = InnoDB) */
```

and my question was:
why Count returns no record,
but IFNULL has value???

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: No, it is not a bug.

Comment: Count return no record, why ifnull return value?

Comment: Do you have null values in your tables? Also, provide us with sample data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic of why you are seeing what you observe is that `COUNT` is an *aggregate* function.  When used without `GROUP BY`, it will return a count across the entire table.  Also important, it will always return a single record, even if no records are in the actual table.  Using `COUNT` in the select clause also means that only other aggregate functions or scalar constants may appear.  The reason you see a sum of money is that it comes from a subquery which generates a single scalar value.

While this may be hard to tease apart, it certainly is not a bug in MySQL.

Comment: I told my mate to use Standard SQL, but I still didn't understand, why mysql support:
SELECT field1, field2, sum(num) FROM tb GROUP BY field1

the group by has no field2

Comment: The query you wrote is possibly invalid, if `field1` is not a primary key column.

Comment: no no no, this sql is valid, and can execute in mysql, but invalid in MSSQL.
and thanks for your answer,my question was modified, COUNT + SUM, the quesion still exists

Comment: @youbl no no no it is NOT valid SQL and though it may execute on certain configurations of MySQL, the results will be non deterministic.  I have answered your question, please don't change or it could draw downvotes.

Comment: yes, the result  will be non deterministic. Thanks a lot.